# C++ compilation error using unary und binary function objects

Tags: c++, operators, unary-operator, binary-operators

I have a short question regarding a shot C++ code snippet. I get a compilation error, as soon as i want to evaluate the `()` operator (last line before return of 0 in the main method). The code looks like this:

```
    #include <functional>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

 //multiplication by 10
template <typename A, typename B>
struct multiply_by_ten : unary_function<A, B> {
  B operator()(A& a) {
    return a*10;
  }
};

//addition of the paramters
template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
struct add: binary_function<A, B, C> {

   C operator()(A& a, const B& b) {
        return  a + b;
}
  };

template <typename BinOp, typename Op1, typename Op2>
class combineops_t : public unary_function<typename Op1::argument_type,typename       BinOp::result_type>

{
protected:
   BinOp o; Op1 o1; Op2 o2;
public:
combineops_t(BinOp binop, Op1 op1, Op2 op2) : o(binop), o1(op1), o2(op2) {}

typename BinOp::result_type operator()( const typename Op1::argument_type &x) {
    return o(o1(x),o2(x));
   }
     };



int main(int argc, char **argv) {
add<int, int, int> a;
multiply_by_ten<int, int> b;
multiply_by_ten<int, int> c;

combineops_t<binary_function<int, int, int> , unary_function<int, int> , unary_function<int, int> >
z(a, b, c);
cout << z(13);

return 0;
}
```

Compilation error is in german but it basically says that..

> there is now accordance for the invocation of".

Comment: The error message in english is supposed to be "No match for call to...", I believe. My german is rusty, but I doubt the correctness of you translation :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you change type of your type argument to `std::unary_function` and `std::unary_function` do not have a function call operator!!

In situations like this that you have complicated structure for your template and its arguments the best way is to write a helper function that instantiate template for you:

```
template< class BinOp, class OP1, class OP2 >
combineops_t<BinOp, OP1, OP2> combine_ops( BinOp const& bop, OP1 const& op1, OP2 const& op2 )
{
    return combineops_t<BinOp, OP1, OP2> ( bop, op1, op2 );
}

int main() {
    ...

    auto z = combine_ops( a, b, c );
    std::cout << z( 13 );
}
```

If your compiler does not support C++11 `auto` just use this:

```
combineops_t<
    add<int, int, int>,
    multiply_by_ten<int, int>,
    multiply_by_ten<int, int>
> z( a, b, c );
```

And beside that there is another error in your code, in `multiply_by_ten` and `add` templates you get `a` parameter by reference so just convert `A&` in those templates to `A const&`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your idea with the helper method but then I get a new error:  ../CombineOps.cpp:56:2: Warnung: »auto« will change meaning in C++0x; please remove it

Comment: @user1765902 Sorry this day every thing is about C++11 and I think you have it, so see my updated answer

Comment: this will give me the same error as mentioned above (first post).

Comment: @user1765902 You have another error in your code, again see my edited answer

Comment: Perfect, now it works perfectly. Thanks a lot, aprreciate it!